# Autocomplete box tabindex

Tags: wpf

i have just put

```
two textbox(tabindex=0,2),
one autocompletebox(tabindex=1)
 and one button(tabindex=3)
```

but in runtime autocompletebox get tab at last.

setting tab with

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"
```

try with every mode of KeyboardNavigation

I have also putted control in xaml as per it tabindex order.

Now why autocompletebox come last? and what is solution of it

Comment: Is "autocompletebox" a self-written control?

Comment: using control from WPFTookit -`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"`

Comment: Where are the controls "hosted"? In a StackPanel, or what else? Please provide a code sample.

Comment: `  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtGroupName"  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"  />
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>            

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <Button  Content="Save" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"  />
        </StackPanel>
</Gird>`

Comment: I get my solution doing this.. `<Style TargetType="TextBox">

                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TabIndex}"/>`

                </Style>

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of use for this control. Set the TabIndex or any TextBox's property on the style:

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                          FilterMode="Contains" 
                          IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" 
                          MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
                          Text="{Binding Path=City,
                                         Mode=TwoWay,
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
          <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="1" />
          </Style>
        </controls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox.BorderBrush>
          <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,20">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.05" Color="#ABADB3" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.07" Color="#E2E3EA" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#E3E9EF" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </controls:AutoCompleteBox.BorderBrush>
      </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer that helped me.  The TabIndex and IsTabStop properties must be set on the contained textbox control on the autocompletebox.  If it's done on the AutoCompleteBox, it is either ignored, or causes the control to be "focused" but with the focus not in the part that allows text to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:

> One caveat about the AutoCompleteBox is that it does not recognize the TabIndex property. It is currently just a direct port of the Silverlight control and apparently Silverlight does not have a TabIndex concept. It turns out that the TabIndex property isn’t really needed in WPF either, you will always tab through your controls in the order they are defined in your XAML. So to ensure tab order will be respected, do not set the TabIndex property on any of your controls and just make sure you place them in the XAML in the desired tab order.

[Source](http://lucisferre.net/2010/02/27/wpf-autocompleteboxe280a6-finally/)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add

```
IsTabStop="True"
```

on the autocompletebox